# A countdown timer in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, timer, countdown

I wish to creat a countdown timer in OpenGL.  So I am just looking for a function that will be called every second based on the system clock which will decrease a set variable. I tried fiddling with glutTimerfunc but itcalls back only once. I need a similar setup but one that calls back multiple times.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with OpenGL?

Answer (score 2):

Timers and timer functions are neither defined by C++ nor by OpenGL but rather by the operating system you are using.

However, since GLUT seems to define one, and you are using it, here we go:

In your timer function passed to `glutTimerFunc`, just call `glutTimerFunc` with the same parameters again. That way you will end up creating an infinite loop of timer callbacks.
Use some global variable or the `int` value passed to the timer function to determine when to break the loop.